# typeerror for mathematical operations and comparison operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, typeerror

There is a part in my code wherein I have to use math operations and comparison operators.

For example:

```
avail_res = [4, 2] # avail_res[0] gives me int
r_select_act = [2] # list
score = [2, 4, 0, 6] # list
```

The code I am thinking is something like this:

```
avail_res[0] = avail_res[0] - r_select_act
avail_res[0] = avail_res[0] + r_select_act
```

Moreover, there is a conditional statement in my code that goes like this:

```
for num in score: # num gives int type
    if num <= avail_res[0] and num != 0:
```

Any help/suggestion to get rid of this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    avail_res[0] = avail_res[0] - r_select_act
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'
```

Thank you!
I tried getting the type of the different values. (see comment)

EDIT: 
r_select_act can have more than one value or none at all. 
  for example, r_select_act = [2, 3], therefore all I have to do is to subtract avail_res[0] with both 2 and 3. Moreover if r_select_act is null, this should give me a zero value for r_select_act. Therefore, avail_res[0] = avail_res[0] - 0.

Comment: The problem you are facing is that `r_select_act` is a list and `avail_res[0]` is an int. try this `avail_res[0] - r_select_act[0]`.

Comment: You really need to provide the entire traceback when you're reporting problems with an error message (you seem to have discovered, from your comments, that you're subtracting a list from an int -- and that doesn't seem well defined).

Comment: Your trying to ``sub`` 'int' and 'list', what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @Sushanth I am trying to subtract avail_res[0] = 4 with the values in r_select_act = 2. however, r_select_act can contain more than one value.

Comment: @thebjorn edited my question already

Comment: I am seeing only one value in `r_select_act`. If you can give a more precise example of what you are trying to achieve, maybe I can help

Comment: @Sashaank please see edit of my question.

Answer (score 0):

This message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    avail_res[0] = avail_res[0] - r_select_act
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'
```

says that this is an int:

```
avail_res[0]
```

this this is a list:

```
r_select_act
```

and that the minus operator is not defined on `int - list`.

The minus operator is defined on `int - int`, so perhaps you want to extract an element from the list?

```
avail_res[0] = avail_res[0] - r_select_act[0]
```

Comment: I tried doing this already! But I am getting another error of Index: list index out of range, since r_select_act can contain more than one value or be a null set (which in this case should give me just 0 for r_select_act)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood in the question,

```
avail_res = [4, 2]
r_select_act = [2, 3]
score = [2, 4, 0, 6]

# new code from here

# create a new list calculations to hold all the subtractions.
calculation = []

# condition to check if r_select_act is not empty
if len(r_select_act) != 0:
    # loop through all values in r_select_act
    for i in r_select_act:
        # substract avail_res[0] with each value in r_select_act and append it to calculations.
        calculation.append(avail_res[0] - i)

# if r_select_act is empty then calculation equals avail_res
else:
    calculation = avail_res

print(calculation)
```

If you print out `calculation` it will hold the values [2,1] because `4-2=2` and `4-3=1`